# how to store static data on firebase which is common to each and every user

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i have an excel file which contains all my data.
my app uses this data and i want to store this static data on Firebase and this data is common to all users,so i don't want to store this data again and again. Basically this data is needed for back end works.
I have already tried using event listeners,but it did not work.
So, i want to know how can i store my static data(which is not accessible by user and is to be used for back end work) on Firebase and then how can i retrieve it?
thanking u all in advance.

Comment: What was wrong with what you tried? Question doesn't show your code or what the errors/problems were.